# Force Jenkins to fail if it cannot find a given number of test reports

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins

Is there any way to force a Jenkins build to fail if a minimum number of unit tests have not been executed? For instance, say I had 300 unit tests being ran by Jenkins and I changed something (generating failsafe-reports before, but now are generating surefire-reports) so that Jenkins only found 3 test reports and could not find the remaining 297 reports. Can I specify a minimum number of tests being ran in order to have the build be successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) might be the solution you are looking for.